# UI not updating while looping through IP Addresses

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, user-interface

I have a simple work to do, On button click it will get all Network IP addresses from a range, loop through them and put the active  in a list. While performing the process a panel will be shown on which ip address will be displayed that is being checked. Code runs fine but form hangs up, application go to not responding and ip address not displayed even panel is not shown. how to do that?
my code is:

```
private void btnAutoSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel_Search.Visible = true; // Not Working
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        string ipBase = getIPAddress();
        string[] ipParts = ipBase.Split('.');
        ipBase = ipParts[0] + "." + ipParts[1] + "." + ipParts[2] + ".";



        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            string ip = ipBase + i.ToString();
            Ping p = new Ping();                
            PingReply pingresult = p.Send(ip, 100);
            if (pingresult.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                lstIPs.Add(ip);
                lblConnecting.Text = ip;  // Not Working

            }

        }


        GridConn.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (string s in lstIPs)
        {
            Device obj = new Device();
            obj.IPAddress = s;
            lblConnecting.Text = s;
            int vSMSLimit = 0;
            int.TryParse(txtSMSLimit.Text, out vSMSLimit);
            obj.SMSLimit = 0;
            if (obj.ConnectToHostServer())
            {
                obj.SendConnectionMessage();
                obj.ReceiveConnectionMessage();
                MyDevices.lst.Add(obj);
                GridConn.Rows.Add(true, obj.IPAddress, obj.PhoneModel, obj.PhoneStatus, obj.SoftwareVersion);
            }
        }


         Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        panel_Search.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Use a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8) to move the network communications off the UI thread

Comment: thanks that will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the UI must be updated from the 'Main' thread (always called UI thread), but if you do other processing on this thread then the UI itself will lock up.  So you should put long running process onto another thread.

This will cause the problem however that this thread cannot update the UI, as it is not the Main/UI thread.  So then you have to invoke the UI thread yourself to update it.

Luckily there is simple way of doing this using the BackgroundWorker class in C# which can help you a lot.  But you need to separate out your UI and background tasks.

```
//Define worker
BackgroundWorker myBGWorker;


//Initalise worker and start it from your button
private void btnAutoSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel_Search.Visible = true; // Not Working
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    myBGWorker = new BackgroundWorker()

    //This method will execute your processing on a background thread
    myBGWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);

    //This method will execute when your background worker finishes
    //It runs on the Main/UI thread
    myBGWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);

    //This method will execute when the background thread wants to update the progress
    //It runs on the Main/UI Thread
    myBGWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);

    //Tell it we will be reporting progress
    myBGWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    //Start!
    myBGWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
}

private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)  
{  
        string ipBase = getIPAddress();
        string[] ipParts = ipBase.Split('.');
        ipBase = ipParts[0] + "." + ipParts[1] + "." + ipParts[2] + ".";

        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            string ip = ipBase + i.ToString();
            Ping p = new Ping();                
            PingReply pingresult = p.Send(ip, 100);
            if (pingresult.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                lstIPs.Add(ip);

                //Below reports the progress.  The number shouuld represent the percentage of process, the object can be anything you want
                double percentDone = (100.0 / 255.0) * i;            
                e.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(percentDone), ip);
            }

        }
}  

private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lblConnecting.Text = e.UserState as string;  
}


private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Cancelled) 
        MessageBox.Show("Operation was canceled");  
    else if (e.Error != null) 
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);  
    else 
    {
       GridConn.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (string s in lstIPs)
        {
            Device obj = new Device();
            obj.IPAddress = s;
            lblConnecting.Text = s;
            int vSMSLimit = 0;
            int.TryParse(txtSMSLimit.Text, out vSMSLimit);
            obj.SMSLimit = 0;
            if (obj.ConnectToHostServer())
            {
                obj.SendConnectionMessage();
                obj.ReceiveConnectionMessage();
                MyDevices.lst.Add(obj);
                GridConn.Rows.Add(true, obj.IPAddress, obj.PhoneModel, obj.PhoneStatus, obj.SoftwareVersion);
            }
        }

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        panel_Search.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Desktop applications use one single thread to handle UI, and event handlers run synchronously on the UI thread, that is why form hangs, because it cannot handle other UI interactions while the event handler is running.

Best practice is that event handlers take UI thread for very short time.

When you need to perform long running tasks because of user interaction, you should perform the task in another thread, you should not use the UI thread for long running tasks.

You can use BackgroundWorker to move the task to another thread, but it is better to use asynchronous event handlers.

For example:

```
private async void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await PerformLongRunningTaskAsync();
    //TODO: update UI after completing task

    await Task.Run(() => PerformLongRunningTaskSynchronously());
    //TODO: update UI after completing task;
}

private async Task PerformLongRunnigTaskAsync() {
   //TODO: implement this async method
}

private void PerformLongRunningTaskSynchronously() {
  //TODO: implement this synchronus method
}
```

Your code should be something like this:

```
private async void btnAutoSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel_Search.Visible = true; // Not Working
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        string ipBase = getIPAddress();
        string[] ipParts = ipBase.Split('.');
        ipBase = ipParts[0] + "." + ipParts[1] + "." + ipParts[2] + ".";



        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            string ip = ipBase + i.ToString();
            Ping p = new Ping();                
            PingReply pingresult = await p.SendPingAsync(ip, 100);
            if (pingresult.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                lstIPs.Add(ip);
                lblConnecting.Text = ip;  // Not Working

            }

        }


        GridConn.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (string s in lstIPs)
        {
            Device obj = new Device();
            obj.IPAddress = s;
            lblConnecting.Text = s;
            int vSMSLimit = 0;
            int.TryParse(txtSMSLimit.Text, out vSMSLimit);
            obj.SMSLimit = 0;
            if (await Task.Run(() => obj.ConnectToHostServer())
            {
                await Task.Run(() => obj.SendConnectionMessage());
                await Task.Run(() => obj.ReceiveConnectionMessage());
                MyDevices.lst.Add(obj);
                GridConn.Rows.Add(true, obj.IPAddress, obj.PhoneModel, obj.PhoneStatus, obj.SoftwareVersion);
            }
        }


         Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        panel_Search.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did the work thanks to Brian Rogers,

```
 private void btnAutoSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;


        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

    }

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                panel_Search.Location = new Point(380, 72);
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                string ipBase = getIPAddress();
                string[] ipParts = ipBase.Split('.');
                ipBase = ipParts[0] + "." + ipParts[1] + "." + ipParts[2] + ".";



                for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    string ip = ipBase + i.ToString();
                    Ping p = new Ping();                                                
PingReply pingresult = p.Send(ip, 100);
                    if (pingresult.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        lstIPs.Add(ip);                            
                        lblConnecting.Text = ip;
                        //listBox1.Items.Add(ip);                
                    }

                }




                GridConn.Rows.Clear();
                foreach (string s in lstIPs)
                {
                    Device obj = new Device();
                    obj.IPAddress = s;
                    lblConnecting.Text = s;
                    int vSMSLimit = 0;
                    int.TryParse(txtSMSLimit.Text, out vSMSLimit);
                    obj.SMSLimit = 0;
                    if (obj.ConnectToHostServer())
                    {
                        obj.SendConnectionMessage();
                        obj.ReceiveConnectionMessage();
                        MyDevices.lst.Add(obj);
                        GridConn.Rows.Add(true, obj.IPAddress, obj.PhoneModel, obj.PhoneStatus, obj.SoftwareVersion);
                    }
                }

                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                panel_Search.Location = new Point(333, 252);

            }
        }
    }
```